# Hierarchies with multiple parents in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tree

I'm looking how to implement a query that returns all ancestors (at all levels, so it includes the direct ancestors, the ancestor's ancestors, and so on ) for all nodes in a hierarchy that allows multiple parents for a specific node.

Given the following table structure:

```
Table Nodes: Id, Name
Table Relations: IdNode, IdParentNode
```

A similar question is [SQL Server - Get all children of a row in many-to-many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285285/sql-server-get-all-children-of-a-row-in-many-to-many-relationship), but I didn't succeed to adapt it to my case.

Comment: This question needs to specify additional details about the requirements for the solution. As it stands, you have specified additional details in each answer in response to the answer, which were not originally included in the question. To prevent confusion, please add those details here and be a little more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @IdNode INT -- use the correct data type
SET @IdNode = 1  -- here use the node you want to search

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  IdNode, 
            IdParentNode Ancestor, 
            1 TreeLevel
    FROM Relations
    WHERE IdNode = @IdNode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  A.IdNode, 
            B.IdParentNode,
            TreeLevel + 1
    FROM CTE A
    INNER JOIN Relations B
        ON A.Ancestor = B.IdNode
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 200)
```

The `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 200)` means that it looks only 200 levels deep, you can use `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)` if you want to setup that for all the levels (though make sure that the query can finish before doing that).

Comment: @user3104183 then why did you asked "for a specific node in a hierarchy"?

Comment: @user3104183 Anyway, you *can* remove the `WHERE IdNode = @IdNode` from my answer, but I have to advice you to not create that view, it will be really really slow, and has the potential to hang your server

Comment: This will only the first level of ancestors.

Comment: @JLo You are right, bad copy-paste for the `JOIN`, fixed it now

Comment: I figure out, but when I try to remove duplicates (A has B, C as parents and B is a child of C), I get this error message when I modify **UNION ALL** with **UNION**: `Recursive common table expression 'CTE' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator`

Comment: @user3104183 That's a limitation of recursive CTEs, you need to use `UNION ALL`. You might use `DISTINCT` on the last `SELECT`, but you should know that it will have an impact on the probably bad performance that already had. And if you do create it as a `VIEW`, you'll need to remove the `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 200)` and instead use it when you do the `SELECT` from that view

Comment: I don't think the performance will be a problem, as I have up to 200 rows, with 1-2 levels depth.

Comment: @user3104183 well, you'll need to test it to see, I just need to make sure to warn you about the potential issues. But with that number of rows and levels on your tree it shouldn't be a big problem. You'll also need to make sure that you don't add a row on your `relations` table that makes a circular reference between a node and a parent (and also never to add a row with a node that has itself as a parent)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to query the hierarchy, you can use `hierarchyid` and benefit greatly from it.
This will allow you to query specific levels and make advanced queries that will filter and aggregate data based on node levels and much more. It will also let you return all of the children of a specific node, which is what you want to do.

But, that also means using a different table structure than what you have listed.
If you are interested in `hierarchyid` you can look at [this information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx).

Comment: As I understood, HierarchyID cannot be used for hierarchies with multiple parents...

Comment: @user3104183 That is correct, it will not work correctly out of the box. But you can add support for it by treating the system as many trees and then link the trees by concatenating them during updates and inserts when they overlap and by making a joining table that represents trees that are parents of other trees. It's more cumbersome but works well still.